# Limiting value of definite integral

Tags: integration

$$I = \int_{-4}^4 e^{in\pi x/4}\frac{\sinh(b\pi/4)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{a-x}{8/\pi}\right)+\sinh^2(b\pi/8)}\,dx$$

I am unable to integrate the above equation when when $b$ tends to $0$, because of a singularity when $x$ tends to $a$; can anyone please help me to solve the above integration.

Answer (score 0):

since (see for example [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9574/limit-of-lorentzian-is-dirac-delta))
$$\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sinh(b\pi/4)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{a-x}{8/\pi}\right)+\sinh^2(b\pi/8)}=\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\frac{16b/\pi}{(a-x)^2+b^2}=16\,({\rm sign}\,b)\delta(x-a),$$
the small-$b$ limit of your integral equals
$$\lim_{b\rightarrow 0}I=\begin{cases}
16e^{in\pi a/4}\,({\rm sign}\,b)&\text{if}\;\;|a|<4,\\
0&\text{if}\;\;|a|>4.
\end{cases}$$